# How do I spawn 10 threads to process a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, dictionary, asynchronous

I have a dictionary of usernames, I want to check whether these users can be used for login into a website, but iterating it one by one would last long since it's a huge list, I want it to run in max 10 threads, testing 10 at once.

```
Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string,string>;
test.Add("user1", "pass1");
test.Add("user2", "pass2");
...
test.Add("user999", "pass999");
```

How do I spawn 10 threads and process it, then combine all the result into a new Dictionary containing only user that pass the login test? Example of the site (not real site, only to demonstrate that this function return true for successful login and false for wrong login).

```
private bool IsLoginSuccess(string u, string p)
{
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
  string str = wc.DownloadString("http://www.samplesite.com?user=" + u + "&pass=" p);
  if (str == "1") return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: sorry it should be 10 threads, ignore the 4 above. My problem is I am unable to combine all the result return from 10 threads into a single Dictionary that contains all successful login from the 10 threads I have spawn.

Comment: Are you only *reading* from the original dictionary in parallel? I suspect that `Parallel.ForEach` is appropriate here, with appropriate accumulation. Each thread can accumulate results in a dictionary for itself, then merge them at the end. Or you could use a thread-safe dictionary.

Comment: Just so you know, it is doubtful that processing this with 10 threads will benefit you over single threaded. In fact, I believe processing this with 10 threads will result in SLOWER performance.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer: What makes you think that, given that the task to perform on each entry is network-bound?

Comment: Hi Jon, yes the original Dictionary is for reading only, I have problems in combining the result from all the 10 threads, will there be issue such as locking since 10 threads need to access a new Dictionary to add username/password to it if it success. Can you show me example using Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: Locking to output dictionary could be a bottleneck if task are extremely short, if they take longer than 50 ms then lock to output dictionary should not be a problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet, exactly, it is network bound, not cpu bound. Add the overhead from creating 10 threads and then locking the output dictionary.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer: I think you've missed my point - it's network bound, and those network connections can be parallelized. Why would you *not* want to make the requests in parallel? It's unlikely to be *bandwidth* limited - it's much more likely to be the latency of each request, and using multiple connections will make that more efficient.

Comment: Well you could be correct @Jon Skeet. We would need more info to know for sure. But I doubt that the input size is big enough to justify starting up the threads. Personally, I would go with an asnch request over explicitly creating 10 threads.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer: If the roundtrip time is 100ms (which would be reasonably fast...) then processing 1000 entries in series would take 100 seconds. Just how expensive do you think it is to create 10 threads? :)

Comment: By the way, is Parallel.ForEach stop until all threads and all items finish processing or will it just step over?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's still Monday morning across the pond, I need some coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you're looking to use lots of connections to a single site, you may well want to tweak the process configuration to allow that - otherwise you'll find you get a bottleneck on the `WebClient`. See the [`<connectionManagement>` app.config element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc) for that.

The simplest approach would probably be to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` to collect the results, and `Parallel.ForEach` to process the original dictionary in multiple threads. (It's safe to *read* the dictionary from multiple threads, so long as nothing is writing to it.)

```
var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
Parallel.ForEach(test,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
    pair =>
    {
        if (IsLoginSuccess(pair.Key, pair.Value))]
        {
            results[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, you could do everything with asynchronous requests - easier with C# 5 than C# 4, mind you.

Comment: hi Jon thanks for the code. May I know is there benefit between asynchronous requests over parallel.foreach? I use C# 4 actually

Comment: @lostincomputer2: Well async generally feels cleaner, in that you can just make *all* the requests asynchronously, then wait for them all to complete (also asynchronously) - no threads will be tied up waiting for responses. Is there any reason you're still using C# 4, btw? Note that you can use C# 5 but still target .NET 4, and there's a BCL targeting pack to allow C# 5 async methods while targeting .NET 4.

Comment: I am using VS2013, and targetting .NET 4.0, my thought is that its C# 4? Am I wrong?

Comment: @lostincomputer2: No, that's C# 5, but still targeting .NET 4. So if you use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) you can use `async` methods.

Comment: oh I see, I will read more about async, and my library does not support async yet, will port it to use async, thanks for highlighting